# Error ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle, listener

Whenever I try to start the listener (I just have only one Oracle database) I get the following:

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=admin-41f89f35d)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
 # TNSNAMES.ORA Network Configuration File: F:\Oracle\network\admin\tnsnames.ora  
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.  

    PROJECT =  
      (DESCRIPTION =  
        (ADDRESS_LIST =  
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = admin-xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))  
        )  
        (CONNECT_DATA =  
          (SERVICE_NAME = PROJECT)  
        )  
      )  

    INST1_HTTP =  
      (DESCRIPTION =  
        (ADDRESS_LIST =  
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = admin-xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))  
        )  
        (CONNECT_DATA =  
          (SERVER = SHARED)  
          (SERVICE_NAME = MODOSE)  
          (PRESENTATION = http://HRService)  
        )  
      )  

    EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =  
      (DESCRIPTION =  
        (ADDRESS_LIST =  
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))  
        )  
        (CONNECT_DATA =  
          (SID = PLSExtProc)  
          (PRESENTATION = RO)  
        )  
      )
```

**listerner.ora**

```
# LISTENER.ORA Network Configuration File: F:\Oracle\network\admin\listener.ora  
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.  

LISTENER =  
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =  
    (DESCRIPTION =  
      (ADDRESS_LIST =  
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = admin-xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))  
      )  
    )  
  )  

SID_LIST_LISTENER =  
  (SID_LIST =  
    (SID_DESC =  
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)  
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Oracle)  
      (PROGRAM = extproc)  
    )  
    (SID_DESC =  
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PROJECT)  
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Oracle)  
      (SID_NAME = PROJECT)  
    )  
  )
```

I really don't know what the problem is. My tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files looks fine to me.

Comment: yes , the default listener

Comment: What does it say if you try "startup" at the LSNRCTL> prompt?

Comment: Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Failed to start service, error 2.
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
  32-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: Do you have a supported OS you can run this from?  That error appears to be caused by bad network settings, according to Google.  Can you verify your hostname is set properly with ping and such before we spend more time troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, you can just remove the entries (with respect to your database)from both the tnsnames.ora and listerner.ora.
In your scenario, remove this from tnsnames.ora

```
 PROJECT =  
      (DESCRIPTION =  
        (ADDRESS_LIST =  
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = admin-xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))  
        )  
        (CONNECT_DATA =  
          (SERVICE_NAME = PROJECT)  
        )  
      )
```

and this from listerner.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =  
  (SID_LIST =  
    (SID_DESC =  
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)  
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Oracle)  
      (PROGRAM = extproc)  
    )  
    (SID_DESC =  
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PROJECT)  
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Oracle)  
      (SID_NAME = PROJECT)  
    )  
  )
```

and then you can try to open up the database.
These entries would be created automatically.
And we hope the listener listens to us this time.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your Oracle software is installed in F:\Oracle:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=F:\Oracle
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

lsnrctl start
```

should do the trick.
If you work with Oracle, make sure that the environment is setup correctly. Also note that if you have multiple Oracle installations on the same Windows machine, the PATH is modified such that the last installed Oracle installation is selected first from PATH. That gives quite a few side effects.

Answer (score -1):

If "tnsnames.ora" and "listener.ora" files looks fine and still you are getting errors then try the following simple steps

1. Go to start->Run [windows button + r]
2. Type "services.msc"
3. From the services window, try to find "OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener"
4. Just right click on it and click on "start"
5. Check the status in command prompt [c:\windows\System32> lsnrctl status]

hope the listener listens !

Try to open up the database now